# translation invariant distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

This question makes me confused: 
If $h \in R^n $ let $\tau_h $ be the translation operator. Determine all distributions $u$ such that $\tau_h u=u$

I started by taking Fourier transform for both sides, but then I don`t know!

$ u(x-a)=u(x)$

$ e^{-i2\pi x a} u^{\land}=u^{\land}$

then??

Comment: Then it follows that $\operatorname{supp} \hat{u} \subset \{0\}$. (But taking the Fourier transform assumes the distribution is tempered, perhaps a different approach is preferable.)

Comment: yes, you are right but I don`t know what to do with it!

Comment: What does translation-invariance imply about the derivatives of $u$?

Comment: I seriously don`t know

Comment: What does it imply about the difference quotients?

Comment: I`m seriously lost now !!! :(

Comment: Consider first the case that $u$ is regular, i.e. there is a locally integrable function such that $$u[\varphi] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$$ for all test functions $\varphi$.

Comment: $\int_{R^n} f(x+h) \varphi (x) dx - \int_{R^n} f(x) \varphi (x) dx = \int_{R^n} f(x)[\varphi (x-h)-\varphi (x)] dx$

Comment: I feel actually like I`m getting very confused and mixing everything!

Comment: What does the translation-invariance of $u$ say about $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)[\varphi(x-h) - \varphi(x)]\,dx\,?$$

Comment: $ \int_{R^n} f(x)[\varphi(x-h)-\varphi(x)] dx=\int_{R^n} f(x) \varphi (x) dx$ so $\int_{R^n} f(x) [\varphi (x-h)-2\varphi (x)] dx=0$

Comment: No, that's incorrect. By the translation-invariance, what is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x+h)\varphi(x)\,dx\,?$$

Comment: $\int _{R^n} f(x) \varphi(x) dx $

Comment: so $ \int_{R^n} f(x) [\varphi (x-h) - \varphi (x)] dx = 0 $?

Comment: Right. Now, what does that say about $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} u$?

Comment: if we apply what we did above to $ u$ instead of $f$ we would get that the derivative is zero?

Comment: well, if this is correct that would mean $ u$ is the constant distribution.

Comment: Yes. So if $u$ is translation-invariant, all derivatives of $u$ vanish. Can you deduce from that that there is hence a constant $c$ such that $$u[\varphi] = c\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(x)\,dx$$ for all $\varphi$?

Comment: I do notsee any condition on $\varphi$ except it`s a test function?

Comment: That's right. It holds for all test functions, and thus we see that a translation-invariant distribution is induced by a constant function. But an argument is needed to go from the vanishing of the derivatives to the conclusion that up to a constant factor the distribution is integration.

Comment: seriously thanks A LOT for you.